# Clicar em botão dar zoom para mostrar o país inteiro (Brasil) no Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Olá gostaria que por favor me ajudassem com um exemplo de como fazer para quando o usuário clicar em um botão ao lado do mapa fazer com que o mapa dê o zoom para mostrar o país inteiro.

Eu não consegui fazer um exemplo prático. Acho que com essas informações dá pra entender o que desejo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Brasil" id="moveToBrasil" /><br>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
var map;

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(45,19),
    zoom:3,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

$('#moveToBrasil').click(function(){
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng( -14.235004 , -51.92528 ) );
});
```

JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/giancarlodebian/6h3frLaz/4/

Referências:

https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv